# mysql_connect vs mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, database

i'm having a bit of an issue trying to use mysqli_connect the same way i use mysql_connect

this would be an example of my code:

**QUERY.PHP**

```
class classQuery{
  public function __construct(){
    require('conex/classConex.php');
    require('conex/statement/classStatement.php');
    $this->ObjConex = new classConex;
    $this->ObjStatement = new classStatement;
  }
  public function Query($email){
    $this->ObjConex->Conex();
    $query='SELECT user_email from table where email='.mysql_real_escape_string($email).'';
    $consulta = $this->ObjStatement->Select($query);
    return $consulta;
  }
```

**CLASS STATEMENT**

```
class classStatement{
  public function __construct(){
    $this->ObjConex = new classConex;
  }
    public function Select($query){
      $query_execute = mysql_query($query);
      while($row = mysql_fetch_row($query_execute)){
         $consulta=htmlentities($row[0]);
      }
      return $consulta; 
    }
}
```

**CLASS CONEX**

```
class classConex{
  public function Conex(){
    require ('conex.php');
    mysql_connect ($server,$dbuser,$dbpasswd) or die('Error de Conexión');
    mysql_select_db($dbname);
  }
}
```

Ok, now i want to use mysqli_connect instead of mysql_connect, according to php manual my new connect class should be something like this:

`$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'my_db');`

now that my connection is an object i won't be able to execute my query from ClassStatement the same way i'm doing it, i have tested returning the object from the connect class but that means more code that i find redundant...is there a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about structuring your class like this:

```
class Database {

  public function __construct ( $server, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname ) {
    $this->dbhandle = new mysqli($server, $dbuser, $dbpasswd, $dbname);
  }

  public function Select ($query) {
    $result = $this->dbhandle->query($query);

    while ( $row = $result->fetch_row() ){
      // Whatever you're doing here...
      //$consulta = htmlentities($row[0]);
    }

    return $consulta; 
  }

}
```

So you could use it with this code:

```
class Query{
  public function __construct(){
    require('conex/classDatabase.php');

    $this->Database = new Database($host, $user, $pass, $dbname);
  }

  public function Query ($email) {
    $query = "SELECT user_email from table where email='".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."'";
    $consulta = $this->Database->Select($query);
    return $consulta;
  }
}
```

I've included the object oriented syntax in my examples. Since you're using objects anyway, you'll probably get along with it.

Comment: thanks @martinCzerwi and ExplosionPills, i now have a much better understading how mysqli_connect works, while martin structure seems to fix my problem the only thing that worries me is that as soon as the object is created, the connection will be executed, meaning that it might be useless if the data comes from my DB cache (memcache), i'm not sure how much this can stress my DB instance, do you guys know if returning the object is recommended for cases such as this? i just want to keep a proper code standard that's easy to understand. thanks!

Comment: I don't really know about memcache and such, but you could aswell put the `new mysqli`-stuff into a new function, instead of `__construct`, like `public function Connect(...)`. That way it doesn't connect on creation.

Comment: ok martinCzerwi,@Explosion Pills, thank you guys for helping me, very much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

`mysql_connect` creates a global connection that you are depending on.  This is already inelegant.  You will have a lot more control (especially if you need to maintain multiple connections simultaneously) if you treat the connection as an object instance -- which is what `mysqli` forces you to do.

It's not redundant either .. it's just clear.

Comment: i still have doubts to decide whether or not returning the object would be the proper method for cases such as this, what would be your recommendation?, i want to have a code that does not only fix the problem but also fixes it the best way possible

Answer (score -2):

Mysqli_connect is the newer version of mysql library.

Here I in mysqli stands for improved.

Few things have been introduced with Mysqli.

They are,

1.Prepared statements.
2.Object oriented interface.
3.Support for multiple statements.
4.Embedded server support.

Comment: Please See this First. [How-do-I-write-a-good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)